# What's the principle of Wolfram's function "Integrate"

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8, wolfram-language

It says"Wolfram uses standard principle to calculate integration"

What does it mean?

Comment: That statement is meaningless without context.

Comment: Yeah.I was confused by its statement.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably it means standard algorithmic methods.  (No special magic.)

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Integration.html

"*The Wolfram Language knows how to do almost any integral that can be done in terms of standard mathematical functions.*"

The following information is from a paper relating to *symbolic* integration in Mathematica 5 and 6.  (The current version is Mathematica 11.)

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5832/DefiniteIntegration.pdf

> Indefinite Integration
>
> The indefinite integration code consists primarily of a partial
>   implementation of the Risch algorithm [2, 5], in addition to extensive
>   table lookup methods. …
>
> Definite Integration
>
> Definite integration is done via a number of methods as indicated
>   below.
>
> - Special case contour integration.
> - Newton−Leibniz code specialized for integrands of the form *rational* x *trig* or *rational* x *exponential*.
> - Newton−Leibniz code specialized for integrands containing logs or polylogs.
> - A general case implementation of Newton−Leibniz integration.
> - An implementation of definite integration by convolution of MeijerG functions [1].

Mathematica also performs numerical integration.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html

Comment: Thank you so much!